# I need Sophie Germain primes in the 7-digit range

Tags: elementary-number-theory

About a year ago some one asked if there was a list of ALL Sophie Germain primes. One answer pointed the questioner to: vaxasoftware.com/doc_eduen/mat/primsophie_en.pdf. That list only goes up to 100,000. I don't need ALL the SG primes - but I need to view into the top end of the 7-digit range. Does anyone know of such a list?

Comment: You could probably test all the 7-digit numbers for primality in less than an hour on any modern computer with a basic factoring algorithm; sieving, you could probably do it in 10-15 minutes at worst...

Comment: I have to correct myself - a simple unoptomized version (with a typical 'for (j=3; j*j<=i; j+=2)' trial divisor loop) ran in less than 15 seconds to produce all the 7 digit SG primes on my low-end Mac laptop.

Comment: I used Wolfram|Alpha to find 9999653. Is that right? I sometimes get safe primes and Sophie Germain primes mixed up.

Answer (score 3):

The OEIS has a list of the first 100000 Sophie Germain primes, the last of which is 19391363: https://oeis.org/A005384/b005384.txt.

Comment: Thank you, Eric - the answer to the SG... the Safe Prime, is in the high 7's low 8-digit range. But I need the actual Sophie Germain numbers to be in that range.

Comment: my mistake - sorry. I see you're right. Thank you!